# awk text processing take values of limits

Tags: text-processing, awk

i have a txt file like this

```
32 1
32 2
32 3
32 4
32 5
17 8
17 9
17 10
17 11
14 33
14 34
14 35
```

and i want to get txt file lke this one ! so we take the limits MIN and MAX of a value in field one from field two and print them .

```
32 1 5
17 8 11
14 33 35
```

any idea ? thank you .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
datamash -t ' ' -g 1 min 2 max 2 < file
```

Output:

```
32 1 5
17 8 11
14 33 35
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'min[$1] == "" || $2 < min[$1] { min[$1] = $2 }
     max[$1] == "" || $2 > max[$1] { max[$1] = $2 }
     END { for (i in min) print i, min[i], max[i] }' file |
sort -rn
```

This remembers the maximum and minimum values associated with the first column in the `max` and `min` associative arrays. These values are printed when all data has been processed.

The `sort -rn` at the end makes sure that the output is sorted in decreasing order.

Answer (score 2):

With input sorted as yours is:

```
$ awk '$1 != p{printf "%s%s",max,$0; p=$1} {max=OFS $2 ORS}  END{printf "%s", max}' file
32 1 5
17 8 11
14 33 35
```